# I need a cell to be a hyperlink and the content from the cell a part of the hyperlink

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

I need a cell to be a hyperlink and the contents of the cell is part of the hyperlink. So in the link under, I added the line CELLCONTENT and that is the part in the hyperlink that should change when i click a cell, the content of the cells is like C1234-1234

`https://text.text.text.net/text/ViewPII.jsp?pii_id=VPROC009105&pii_name=CELLCONTENT&config_week=202017&top_line=VCC1191186&end_item=PRG-VCC42&release_status=Published`

So if i click the cell, the link should be (and also go to the site)

`https://text.text.text.net/text/ViewPII.jsp?pii_id=VPROC009105&pii_name=C1234-1234&config_week=202017&top_line=VCC1191186&end_item=PRG-VCC42&release_status=Published`

This is what i tried
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Hyperlink` expects a string representing the destination to link to.

Should be something like

```
=Hyperlink("https://text.text.text.net/text/ViewPII.jsp?pii_id=VPROC009105&pii_name=" & F2 & _
  "&config_week=202017&top_line=VCC1191186&end_item=PRG-VCC42&release_status=Published", "Text To Display In Cell")
```

where cell `F2`contains part of the link string.

Comment: Do i do this with a macro, or do i do this with an extra cell with a formula?

Comment: =HYPERLINK(https://text.text.text.net/PIIWebSearch/ViewPII.jsp?pii_id=VPROC009105&pii_name= (F2) &config_week=202017&top_line=VCC1191186&end_item=PRG-VCC42&release_status=Published

because first i tried something like this above where (F2) was the cell with content

Comment: @xtreambart please edit your Q to show the whole code you are using to set the link.  Without that I can't help you further

Comment: I put the image in of my excel, i tried to do it with a formula =Hyperlink and on the place of the CELLCONTENT i tried (F2) but i guess your answer was for VBA? It's been ages i used any form of Vb, i believe in that time it still was called VB script.

So fast description of my question = i want all Cells in column F to be part of a hyperlink, so every cell in F will send me to that page in the web browser where the code in the cell defines a different page. Adding the links manually will take me to much time.

Comment: @xtreambart since you tagged the Q as `VBA`of course I answerd with `VBA`.  I've now retagged your Q

Comment: As a formula it is not working, guess i'll need my old vbs skills back. 
So this should be something like.

Var CELLCONTENT